# adressing database manually after release/installation

Tags: c#, database, path, installation

I'm programming a form data bank program.
I needed to read out data manually for this purpose and I think -after long research- this is the best way to address my data base:

```
con = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection();
String connectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.sdf";
String executable = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
String path = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
con.ConnectionString = connectionString;//"Data Source=C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\Databases\\Visual 2012\\Database1.sdf";
con.Open();
```

This works in the visual editor, but after releasing my program and the program installation it gives out a error, because there is no data base in the installed folder.
(After installation the connectionString targets `C:\Users\Tac\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\9E0GCT8K.WVE\KYYL0ERB.678\Program` and there is no database.

Can some one help me with a good ideas, how to make the addressing work after installation?

Comment: You need to **create** an empty database, either upon installation, or when your app is run the first time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the DataDirectory using SetData, one of the locations it will check for is the directory of the executable.

You can include the database (an empty one i guess) with your installer and configure it to be installed in the same directory as the executable.

Or better still use one of the Special Folders in windows.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

You can specify this folder as well in your installer configuration.
Take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2esdf4x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info on special folders and the **File System Editor**

Comment: Could you tell me how I can configure it to be installed in a special directory? :)

Comment: @user2009820 this may create problems for you because of permission issues if you place it in a custom directory. Might be better to put it ApplicationData or any other special folder. I've modified my answer.